# Cannot connect (null)::selectionChanged to QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtableview

I have the following promoted QTableView:

```
class QRightClickableTableView : public QTableView {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit QRightClickableTableView(QWidget *parent = 0): QTableView(parent) {}

private slots:
  void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if(e->button()==Qt::RightButton)
      emit rightClicked();
    else if (e->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
      emit leftClicked();
  }

signals:
  void rightClicked();
  void leftClicked();
};
```

When binding the selectionChanged signal of QRightClickableTableView, but getting an error. In .cpp:

```
QRightClickableTableView *table = ui->dataTableView;
connect(table, SIGNAL(leftClicked()), this, SLOT(on_tableViewLeftClicked()));
connect(table, SIGNAL(rightClicked()), this, SLOT(on_tableViewRightClicked()));

connect(table->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)),
    SLOT(on_tableViewSelectionChanged(QItemSelection)));
table->setModel(model);
```

The leftClicked and rightClicked signals work as expected, but I get error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection) to MyApp::on_tableViewSelectionChanged(QItemSelection)
```

Comment: When do you set the model for your table view? Try setting it before making the signal slot connection

Comment: Duh. Thanks. That was it. Can you make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signal slot connection has failed since `table->selectionModel()` has returned null.

If you set the model for your table before making signal slot connection, `table->selectionModel()` will return a valid model, making the signal slot connection successful.